# GridView Listing Users' Tasks

Tags: list, gridview

I have a task list which I want to visualize with a GridView. I want to display the SharePoint users as columns, and underneath these users, their respectively assigned tasks will be displayed.

This is where I am right now:
[image: This is where I am right now]

This is what I want:
[image: This is what I want]

How do I make this possible? Is it even possible or is there another more suitable approach out there?

Answer (score 1):

The Data View Web Part is all about aggregating and managing data from various data sources, so u can create Custom Views also try........

http://onlinecoder.blogspot.in/2011/05/using-sharepoint-2010-data-view-web.html

Comment: I tried the DVWP and some customization of XSLT, but I didnt manage to utilize it they way I want. Any more pointers?